# How can I await for an async action dispatch on the click of a button?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-redux, jsx, redux-thunk

I have this react component where in the user wants to send in a login request but whenever I dispatch the action, even before it is executed the further code in my component is executed.

I've tried making the login request function as `async` and even tried using await before dispatching the action but it's all been in vain.

Component file:

```
import React from 'react';
import BaseButton from '../BaseButton/BaseButton';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { userLogin } from '../../redux/auth/authActions';
import axios from 'axios';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

function Login({ isLoggedIn, userLogin }) {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(true); //to see if the user wats to login or sign up
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");

  const handleLogin = () => {
    let userCredentials = {
      email: email,
      password: password
    }
        
    userLogin(userCredentials);   // <------ i want to wait for this to execute before the below code is executed

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      console.log('im here');
    } else {
      console.log('wrong credentials');
    }
  }

  const handleSignUp = async () => {

  }

  return login ? (
    <> 
      {*/ ...some JSX for user input */}

          <div className="flex justify-center">
            <BaseButton variant={'solid'} onClick = {handleLogin}>Submit</BaseButton>
          </div>

      {*/ ...some more JSX for user input */}
    <>
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn
  }
}

const dispatchStateToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    userLogin: (userCredentials) => dispatch(userLogin(userCredentials))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchStateToProps)(Login);
```

authActions:

```
import {
  USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOGIN_FAILURE,
} from './authTypes';
import axios from 'axios';

export const sendLoginRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  };
};

export const loginSucccess = () => {
  return {
    type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  };
};

export const loginFailure = (error) => {
  return {
    type: USER_LOGIN_FAILURE,
    payload: error,
  };
};

export const userLogin = (userCredentials) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch(sendLoginRequest());
      axios
        .post('http://localhost:3001/auth/login', userCredentials)
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data.status);
          dispatch(loginSucccess());
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("incorrect credentials");
          dispatch(loginFailure('incorrect credentials'));
        });
    } catch(err) {
      dispatch(loginFailure(err.message));
    }
  };
};
```

auth reducer file:

```
import {
  USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  USER_LOGIN_FAILURE,
  USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
} from './authTypes';

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  isLoggedIn: false,
  error: ''
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS: return{
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        isLoggedIn: true,
    }
    case USER_LOGIN_FAILURE: return{
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        error: action.payload
    }
    default: return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

my store file:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../rootReducer';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export default store;
```

root reducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import authReducer from './auth/authReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `userLogin` action isn't declared `async` nor does it return a Promise so this is why your `handleLogin` handler isn't able to wait for it to complete.

Convert `userLogin` to an `async` action function.

```
export const userLogin = (userCredentials) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch(sendLoginRequest());
    const data = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/auth/login', userCredentials);

    console.log(data.status);

    dispatch(loginSucccess());

    return true; // <-- return resolved value
  } catch(err) {
    dispatch(loginFailure(err.message));
    return false; // <-- return resolved value
  }
};
```

Convert `handleLogin` to an `async` function so it can `await` the dispatched action to resolve. Note that `handleLogin` won't, and ***can't*** see any updated `isLoggedIn` state value from Redux while it has a current value closed over in scope from the time it was called.

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
  const userCredentials = { email, password };
        
  const authSuccess = await userLogin(userCredentials);

  if (authSuccess) {
    console.log('I'm here');
  } else {
    console.log('wrong credentials');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use async await or then catch in handleLogin function and also do not forgot to add return in userLogin and sub functions

```
`const handleLogin = async () => {
    await userLogin(userCredentials); 
    if(isLoggedIn) {
       console.log('here');
    }
}`
```

or use then

```
`userLogin(userCredentials).then(() => { if(isLoggedIn){
          console.log('here');
}});`
```